# webcrawler link extraction problem

Tags: c++

im writing a simple webcrawler. the problem is, with the link extraction.

i uses the cpp-netlib with boost. here a few lines of my CLink Class.

```
    CLink::CLink(const CLink& father, const std::string& relUrl )
    {
     uri = relUrl;
     boost::network::uri::uri instance(relUrl);
     boost::network::uri::uri instanceFather(father.uri);

     if ( (valid = boost::network::uri::is_valid(instance)) == 1)
      {
       scheme    = boost::network::uri::scheme(instance);
       user_info = boost::network::uri::user_info(instance);
       host      = boost::network::uri::host(instance);
       port      = boost::network::uri::port(instance);
       path      = boost::network::uri::path(instance);
       query     = boost::network::uri::query(instance);
       fragment  = boost::network::uri::fragment(instance);

       uri  = scheme;
       uri += "://";
       uri += host;
       uri += path;

      }
     else
      {
       if ( (valid = boost::network::uri::is_valid(instanceFather)) == 1)
        {

         scheme    = boost::network::uri::scheme(instanceFather);
         user_info = boost::network::uri::user_info(instanceFather);
         host      = boost::network::uri::host(instanceFather);
         port      = boost::network::uri::port(instanceFather);
         path      = boost::network::uri::path(instance);
         query     = boost::network::uri::query(instance);
         fragment  = boost::network::uri::fragment(instance);

         uri  = scheme;
         uri += "://";
         uri += host;
         uri += path;

        }
      }
    };

    CLink::CLink( const std::string& _url )
    {

     uri = _url; 
     boost::network::uri::uri instance(_url);
      if ( (valid = boost::network::uri::is_valid(instance) ) == 1)
       {
       scheme    = boost::network::uri::scheme(instance);
       user_info = boost::network::uri::user_info(instance);
       host      = boost::network::uri::host(instance);
       port      = boost::network::uri::port(instance);
       path      = boost::network::uri::path(instance);
       query     = boost::network::uri::query(instance);
       fragment  = boost::network::uri::fragment(instance);


       uri  = scheme;
       uri += "://";
       uri += host;
       uri += path;

         }
        else
      std::cout << "err " << std::endl;
    };
```

the links from the webpage i took with the htmlcxx lib. i took the  HTML::Node and normalize them wih the boost filesystem.

```
 if ( url.find("http://") == std::string::npos)
  {
   std::string path = link.get_path() + url;   
   url =  link.get_host() + path;

   boost::filesystem::path result;
   boost::filesystem::path p(url);
   for(boost::filesystem::path::iterator it=p.begin(); it!=p.end(); ++it)
    {
     if(*it == "..")
      {
       if(boost::filesystem::is_symlink(result) )
    result /= *it;
       else if(result.filename() == "..")
    result /= *it;
       else
    result = result.parent_path();
      }
     else if(*it == ".")
      {
       // Ignore
      }
     else
      {
       // Just cat other path entries
       result /= *it;
      }
    }

   url = "http://" + result.string();
  }

 return ret;
```

Now the problem is.

i try to fetch `http://www.wikipedia.de/` and i get the urls like

properties
http://wikimedia.de/wiki/Vereinszeitung
  ... ...

and on the site `http://wikimedia.de/wiki/Vereinszeitung` there is a link like `/wiki/vereinsatzung`

so often i get links like

```
http://wikimedia.de/wiki/Vereinszeitung/wiki/Freies_Wissen
```

does someone have a idee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a special case for absolute links (those that start with `/`).

If the `href` starts with `/`, then the resulting link should be (using the terms from [The URI template](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/0.8/uri.html) which come from the RFC):

```
[scheme]://[authority][what you got in href]
```

What you are currently constructing is:

```
[scheme]://[authority][path][what you got in href]
```

So you're duplicating the path information.

So if `link.get_path()` starts with `/`, you should simply change:

```
std::string path = link.get_path() + url;   
url =  link.get_host() + path; // this is incorrect btw, missing the [port]
```

to

```
url =  link.get_host() + ":" + link.get_port() + url;
```

It would probably be cleaner to do the path normalization on the path only, not on the URL (i.e. add `host:port` after normalizing the path).

[And I think your code will fail if it encounters an `https` link.]

Comment: thx for answer. but get_path is returning the fill path like /rob/index.html so its fast then /rob/index.html/blaaa ... das suxx :(